# Cant reverse an array of integers using nested for loops

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I have searcher over internet for the answers. Most of them are using temp for reversing the integers. But I want to do it by using nested for loops. Maybe you can find this question useless. But I need help. So please... Help me!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list1= {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] list2 = {7, 8, 9, 0};
    int[] list3 = revv(list1);
    int[] list4 = revv(list2);
    System.out.println(list4);
    System.out.println(list3);

}

public static int[] revv(int[] arr) {
    int[] arr2 = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = arr.length; j>= 0; j--){
            arr[j] = arr2[i];
        }       
    }
    return arr2;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger on your code to figure out where the issue lies?

Comment: Why do you need nested for loops. Just one with `arr2[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1]`

Comment: What's the problem besides `int j = arr.length`?

Comment: `int[] arr2 = null;` and later `arr2[i];` looks suspicious

Comment: *Most of them are using temp for reversing the integers.* Temp what? You'll need either a temp array or temp variable to be able to swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should look like the following. there is no need for a nested loop here.

```
public static int[] revv(int[] arr) {
    int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
    }

    return arr2;
}
```

---

### Advice

To print an array, use `Arrays#toString()`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list3));
```